# How to add animation when changing element style in JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a slide down animation to the element when display being set to `block`, and a slide up when it's `none` or `''`, here's my actual js script:

```js
<script>
  function showQuick(element, icon) {
    var style = element.style
    if (style.display === '') {
      style.display = 'block';
      icon.style.color = '#00FFFF';
      icon.style.filter = 'drop-shadow(0 0 0.35rem #00FFFF)';
    } else if (style.display === 'none') {
      style.display = 'block';
      icon.style.color = '#00FFFF';
      icon.style.filter = 'drop-shadow(0 0 0.35rem #00FFFF)';
    } else {
      style.display = 'none';
      icon.style.color = '#D2042D';
      icon.style.filter = 'drop-shadow(0 0 0.35rem #D2042D)';
    };
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

just try this, it is simple

```css
div {

  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  
  transition: top 1s;

}
```

```html
<div>hello everyone!</div>
```

now when you set **style.top = "0px";** in your code, you will get a sliding effect

Comment: i tried, but i still get no animations, i'm doing it in javascript because i have a really long div with many different elements and icons, so i made that script to can use `onlick` event on the icons and passing the respective element id that i need to edit for that icon, doing it in css will took too many lines :(